# C++ virtual function in type casting of reference

Tags: c++

I have a question in virtual function and reference. It's from a puzzle when I try to prepare interview. I google it for a while but cannot see the exact case.

The code is given as:

```
class A{
public:
 virtual void foo() {cout << "A::foo" << endl;}
};

class B: public A{
public:
 void foo() {cout << "B::foo" << endl;}
};

class C: public B{
public:
 void foo() {cout << "C::foo" << endl;}
};

int main(void){
 C c;

 B *q;
 q = &c; q->foo();
 return 0;
}
```

My thought to the output will be B::foo, but the answer is actually C::foo. Can someone tell me why the vtable wont choose B's implementation? Thanks

Comment: `q` points to an instance of `C`, so that's the version of `foo` that gets called. Can you update your question with your reason *why* you think that the output will be `B::foo`?

Comment: Sorry, I should mentioned this is in C++ in the article

Answer (score 2):

`foo` is virtual in `B` because it overrides a virtual function from a base class even though it is not explicitly declared as `virtual`.

The most derived type of the object called through `q->foo()` is `C` and `C`'s final overrider for `foo` with the signature `void foo()` is `C::foo` so this is the function that is called.

Answer (score 2):

If `foo` was *not* virtual, then the function called would be based on the type of the pointer, and `B::foo()` would be called.

Since `foo` is defined virtual in the base class, it remains virtual in all derived classes. That being the case, the function that's called is based on the type of object pointed *at* rather than the type of the pointer. Since the object pointed at is a `C`, the function that gets called is `C::foo()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `q` points to a `C` object and its virtual function table contains a virtual function `foo`. Remember that any virtual function declared in a class is virtual in any derived class. This is the way of using base classes to access to derived ones.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik:

Once vtables are used - which is in this case forced by the `virtual` declaration of `A::foo` - it's not important what type you declare, it'll always call the method of most specific method - which is in this case `C::foo`.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone tell me why the vtable wont choose B's implementation?

That is the whole point of having virtual functions, so that calling an overriden method through a base class pointer will still call the method from the derived class.

`q` is of type `B *`, but it is pointing to a `C` object. So, when you call the virtual function `foo()` the `C::foo()` implementation gets called.

Even though `foo()` is not marked `virtual` in `B` and `C`, it is still a virtual function because it is declared as such in `A`.

If you want `B::foo()` to get called you'll need to call it explicitly.

```
q->B::foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

`foo()` is a virtual function, which means that the version defined in the class whose instance is **actually** pointed to by `q` is called rather than the one defined in the class in the pointer's type.

Remember that a member function is virtual once it is marked virtual somewhere up the class hierarchy, i.e. one needs not explicitly mark the function as virtual again in classes B and C since this has already been done in class A.